# Auth0 Bad HTTP authentication header format using curl

Tags: curl, auth0

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer fYpIUuMuQyjdjdhrwgk0QUt4_Icz5QBOFHHF3P5mwUJBe_QMvC4Jlib6FIt3SWCWPIYwnD-1" https://dev-amftxahu.us.auth0.com/api/v2/users
```

I am using this command to get users and passing secret id as Bearer but getting below error. I tried client id also but still same error. please take a look

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Bad HTTP authentication header format","errorCode":"Bearer"}%
```

Please check the screenshot also i shared.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The token you're using to authorize the operation is wrong. It does not even look like an access token.

Try this:

In Auth0 dashboard, go to Applications > APIs > Auth0 Management API and move to tab API Explorer. You will see a token there, it is used for testing the Auth0 APIs (be careful, this token has all the scopes so it will allow you to do any operation on your tenant, even delete it!).

Take that token and paste in the headers of your request (after Bearer word).

The process should work.

To get an access token you need to hit the /oauth/token endpoint of the Auth0 Authorization API and to set a machine to machine application that has grant types of client_credentials and is allowed to hit Auth0 management API (default generated) or use the also default generated API Explorer application.

In a machine to machine application, go to Advanced Settings > Grant types and only select Client credentials:

[image]

Then check the Auth0 management API to set permissions and scopes for the application and the tokens that will be generated for that application by going to APIs > Auth0 Management API > Machine to Machine applications. Search your new app and set to authorize if there wasn't already authorized. Then click the dropdown menu and set the scopes you need for the token delivered to that app, in your case, scope read:users should be enough.

Now go to postman or curl and send a request to get a token using that application you have created (with its corresponding client id and client secret):

endpoint: https://dev-amftxahu.us.auth0.com/oauth/token

type: POST

body:

```
{
    "client_id": YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
    "client_secret": YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
    "audience":"https://dev-amftxahu.us.auth0.com/api/v2/",
    "grant_type":"client_credentials"
}
```

You will receive a token with the scopes you set previously.

YOUR CLIENT SECRET IS VERY SENSITIVE INFORMATION BE CAREFUL WITH THAT, IT SHOULD BE ONLY USED WHEN MACHINE TO MACHINE APPLICATIONS ARE INVOLVED, NEVER USE IT IN PUBLIC APPLICATIONS LIKE SPA or MOBILE.

I hope it helps. Sorry for my bad english.